# how can i implement offline storage in android using cache?

Tags: android, caching, offline-storage

Hi I want to implement offline storage in android using cache( like kinvey API)?Can anyone share step wise implementation for same?I searched a lot but don't get much information for Android Cache.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
            Cache.Entry entry = cache.get(API);
            if (entry != null) {
                try {
                    String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(data);
                    FileWriter file = new FileWriter(cxt.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + fileName);
                    String jsonString = jobj.toString();
                    file.write(jsonString);
                    file.flush();
                    file.close();
                  //  prepareListData(jobj);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```